# Effect of AC output impedance on a ratiometric measurement

Tags: measurement

I was planning to make a measurement with a ratiometric IC, so I will sense both the Vcc and the Vout from the chip as shown below. For cleaning up the noise and stability I also want to add a 5V voltage regulator right before the IC. The IC is basically measuring differential pressure.

[image]

I have heard from someone that I might need to verify whether the voltage regulator has a low AC output impedance. What could be reason for such inquiry for this application and why would it matter? What is meant by AC output impedance?

Comment: If your sensors have much higher "impedance" than the voltage regulator' output "impedance", you shouldn't worry much about voltage divider effect.

Comment: *I have heard from someone that...* Next time, ask **WHY**. There are plenty of people in the world willing to give their opinion. If you ask **"why?"** then you will learn to separate the well funded opinions from the less well funded ones. The rogue/unfunded opinion that the output impedance of a regulator matters sends on a quest to find a low AC output impedance regulator. So go back to the person who stated that you need the low AC impedance and let him/her **prove** to you **why** it matters. My guess is that this person cannot do so.

Comment: *For cleaning up the noise and stability* That means you need **decoupling capacitors**. It is always good practice to add these at input and output of regulators. That will give you a low AC impedance. The AC output impedance of the regulator itself then does not matter anymore. See Andy's answer in your other question.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It doesnt matter because I measure both Vcc and Vout?

Comment: No, as Andy explained: the output impedance of a regulator is largely irrelevant because **the decoupling capacitors determine the impedance**. Any noise coupling to the long lines will be sorted to ground by those capacitors. Even if you used a voltage regulator with a very high output impedance the capacitor would still provide a low AC impedance. So: the regulator's impedance is **irrelevant**. Regulators **need** decoupling capacitors. The decoupling capacitors also create a low AC impedance.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you very much it was very clear.