# How to find and compare two regulators' output impedances

Tags: voltage-regulator

I want to compare output impedance of [TL780-05](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl780.pdf) and [LM7805](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/786138.pdf), and also AC output impedance. Which parameter indicates these?

Both are fixed 5V regulators.

I can only see that one of them has 1% accuracy and the other 4%.

Comment: AC output impedance for DC regulators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both devices specify parameters called: -

- Load regulation (how much the output may change under load)
- Output resistance at 1 kHz (related to the above)

Neither device specifies the AC output impedance because it will be always assumed that the parallel output load capacitance will dictate that i.e. 10 uF at (say) 100 kHz has an effective AC impedance of 0.16 ohms.

Comment: Thanks can you also add your answer how can we compare the load regulation? Also this was my previous question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/396036/effect-of-ac-output-impedance-on-a-ratiometric-measurement to be used with this ratiometric chip https://sensing.honeywell.com/honeywell-sensing-trustability-hsc-series-high-accuracy-board-mount-pressure-sensors-50099148-a-en.pdf Maybe you would have an input thanks.

Comment: Thats why I was asking about AC output impedance.

Comment: Load regulation is worse when the mV specified in the data sheet for a given load change is worse for one device compared to another.

Comment: And how did you find that 0.16 Ohm in the datasheet.

Comment: The 0.16 ohm is the impedance of a 10 uF capacitor at 100,000 hertz. In other words the HF AC output impedance of a voltage regulator is determined from about 100 kHz (ball park figure) and upwards by the output capacitor and not the silicon.

Comment: So you are talking about the external cap because that dominates the mOhm level inner output resistance.  It makes very sense if Im not understanding you wrong . And it becomes like 160 Ohm for 100Hz and 1.6kOhm for 10Hz. And how can we relate this output resistance to my previous question, how does it affect the ratiometric measurement? I would be very glad to have your feedback.

Comment: Can I use TL780 without an external output capacitor? Then I can ignore all sort of AC output resistance effect.

Comment: What makes you think the TL780 is any different and can operate properly (is stable) without an output capacitor? Also I wonder **why** the output impedance is so important to you.

Comment: @user1234 no it must be there but remember that the capacitors impedance is shunted the the output impedance of the regulator and, at low frequency, it is a sub ohm value. As frequency rises the regulator output impedance rises but the cap impedance falls and so the baton of low impedance is passed from regulator to capacitor.

Comment: @Andyaka I see since they are in parallel the overall will be again in mOhm level. (?)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It was related also my previous question; https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/396036/effect-of-ac-output-impedance-on-a-ratiometric-measurement

Comment: @user1234 in can be in the milli ohm level at high frequencies because the capacitor ensures that (care of selection of capacitor is important of course) but at DC it will be tens or hundreds of milli ohms. At some frequency around 1 kohm to 10 kohm the combined impedance of regulator and capacitor might be in the ohms area. If this is important then find a regulator that specifies its output impedance as a graph against frequency AND choose a low noise regulator. If the sensor is lowish current you can use a voltage reference to power the device and performance can be really good.

Comment: @Andyaka Im sorry to dig it, but I wonder how did you estimate 1kOhm or 100kOhm for output impedance for the regulator . 
That is huge. At DC, the capacitance has huge resistance; and the regulator has around 20mOhm(from datsheet). 
Since they are parallel the overall becomes less than 20 mOhm. But you say at DC it can be up to kOhm level.
I dont understand this:(

Comment: Oops I meant to say that around 1 kHz to 10 kHz the combined impedance might be in the ohms area.